# Jigsaw Effect While Drawing Basic Triangle

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have been following Android's Training material at https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl however I have went over the guide and remade it twice now and have made changes here and there but can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong? It seems to me that mTriangle is being created multiple times or that the data of it isn't getting removed before redraw, giving it a Jigsaw effect when rotating. My code:

```
class GameRenderer : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private lateinit var mTriangle: Triangle
    private val vPMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
    private val projectionMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
    private val viewMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
    private val rotationMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(unused: GL10, config: EGLConfig) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        mTriangle = Triangle()
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(unused: GL10) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        val scratch = FloatArray(16)
        val time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L
        val angle = 0.090f * time.toInt()
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, -3f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
        Matrix.multiplyMM(vPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0)
        Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0f, 0f, -1.0f)
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, vPMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0)
        mTriangle.draw(scratch)
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(unused: GL10, width: Int, height: Int) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        val ratio: Float = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 3f, 7f)
    }
}
```

That is the code of the Renderer and the Triangle itself is:

```
class Triangle {
    private var mProgram: Int
    private val fragmentShaderCode: String =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
            "\tgl_FragColor = vColor;\n" +
        "}"
    private val vertexShaderCode: String =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
            "\tgl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;\n" +
        "}"

    private var vPMatrixHandle: Int = 0
    private var positionHandle: Int = 0
    private var mColorHandle: Int = 0

    private val COORDS_PER_VERTEX: Int = 3
    private var triangleCoords: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(     // in counterclockwise order:
        0.0f, 0.622008459f, 0.0f,      // top
        -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,    // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f      // bottom right
    )
    private val color: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f)

    private val vertexCount: Int = triangleCoords.size / COORDS_PER_VERTEX
    private val vertexStride: Int = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4

    private var vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer =
        ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleCoords.size * 4).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            asFloatBuffer().apply {
                put(triangleCoords)
                position(0)
            }
        }

    init {
        val vertexShader: Int = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode)
        val fragmentShader: Int = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode)
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram().also {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, vertexShader)
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, fragmentShader)
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(it)
        }
    }

    fun loadShader(type: Int, shaderCode: String): Int {
        return GLES20.glCreateShader(type).also { shader ->
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
        }
    }

    fun draw(mvpMatrix: FloatArray) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram)
        positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition").also {
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                it,
                COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false,
                vertexStride,
                vertexBuffer
            )
            mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor").also { colorHandle ->
                GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, color, 0)
            }
            vPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix")
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(vPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount)
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glClear.xhtml)?

Comment: onSurfaceCreate I clear and I also added it at the top of onDrawFrame as I figured that was the reason, but I'm starting to believe it's somehow somewhere in the Triangle() class it's like it draws all Triangles from the past and then draws adds a new one as well and just keeps duplicating how many to draw when I only call the draw() method once in onDrawFrame

Comment: No you don't. You've to clear the framebuffer in every frame. `glClearColor` is not the same as `glClear`

Comment: Okay thank you very much I will definitely look into this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to clear the framebuffer. Note [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glClearColor.xhtml) specify clear values for the color buffers. But you've to invoke [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glClear.xhtml) to set the values for the buffers:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```